# Initializing a Matrix to NA in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

There is a way to initialize Numeric vector with NA values like.

```
NumericVector x(10,NumericVector::get_na())
```

is there any similar way to initialize a matrix to NA values?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a version that does not waste memory.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix na_matrix(int n){
  NumericMatrix m(n,n) ;
  std::fill( m.begin(), m.end(), NumericVector::get_na() ) ;
  return m ;
}
```

FWIW, in `Rcpp11`, you can use some more expressive syntax:

```
NumericMatrix m(n,n, NA) ;
```

Thanks to this [constructor](https://github.com/Rcpp11/Rcpp11/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h#L24)

Comment: Thank you This is more efficient. Actually I tried the constructor but   as I am using a older version of Rcpp it's not available for me. I am learning a lot from you guys.C++ and Rcpp are awesome :)

Answer (score 7):

Sort of.

Matrices in R really are vectors with a dimension attributes.  So here is one way for a square matrix which generalizes easily to rectangular matrices:

```
R> cppFunction('NumericMatrix foo2(int a) { 
+                  NumericVector v = NumericVector(a*a,NumericVector::get_na()); 
+                  return NumericMatrix(a,a,v.begin()); 
+  }')
> foo2(2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA
R>
```

*Edit:* But for almost all *real work* I use Armadillo matrix classes as they are easy to use, mature, performant and pretty feature-complete. They also have a number of constructors which fill, but (currently?) none for `NA`.  But it is trivial to call the `fill()` method on the matrix constructed:

```
R> cppFunction('arma::mat foo3(int a) {  
+                  return arma::mat(a,a).fill(NA_REAL); 
+              }', depends="RcppArmadillo")
R> foo3(2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA
R>
```

Comment: This allocates the memory for `v` and again for the returned matrix.